# Object frames scale at runtime, but retain constant values, making placing items programmatically difficult/inaccurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, uikit

I'm building an iPhone app for devices running iOS 8 and above, so the app has to be compatible with all iPhones since the 4S.

First, in the storyboard file, I created a view that is the same size as the 4S screen. On that view, I added a grid of 3 rows of 4 rectangles each. I added Autolayout constraints, and everything is playing nicely for the time being. There are no errors or warnings related to misplaced views or conflicting constraints, etc. The rectangles are scaling nicely on all the iPhone simulators.

My problem comes when I try to create and place a button programmatically. The squares in my grid are placeholders where these buttons need to be placed. So, when I create a new button and set it's frame, I'm setting it equal to the frame of one of the rectangles on my grid. When I run the app on the 4S simulator, it works fine, but on every other simulator (with a larger screen), the button is not appearing in the proper place.

What appears to be happening is that each of the rectangles has a set X and Y value in the storyboard editor, and when the app runs in any of the simulators, the X and Y values are remaining constant, even though the view itself is scaling.

To put it more clearly, let's say that slot #2 has an x value of 150 and a y value of 200. Whenever I try to place the button in slot #2 by setting the button's frame equal to slot #2's frame and then run the app, the button's X and Y values are ALWAYS being set to 150 and 200 respectively, instead of being scaled to compensate for the change in size of the device screen. Slot #2 itself is scaling properly, but the button set to Scale #2's frame is being placed at 150/200 regardless.

Has anybody ever experienced this, and if so, do you know how I would get the button's frame to scale with the other elements on the screen?

Let me know if I haven't been clear. Perhaps I can post some pictures to illustrate what I'm getting at.

Edit: Adding some images:

Running on the 4S Simulator. The card appears where it's supposed to in the grid
[image: Image on the 4S Simulator. The card appears where it's supposed to in the grid]

This is on the 6+ Simulator. As you can see, the card appears basically exactly where it would if I were running it on the 4S simulator. When I created it, though, I set it's frame equal to the frame of the second square on the grid.

[image: On the 6+ Simulator. As you can see, the card appears basically exactly where it would if I were running it on the 4S simulator. When I created it, though, I set it's frame equal to the frame of the second square on the grid.]

Comment: Have you used autolayout in such a way that the grid itself is expanding (scaling) as the screen scales up?

Comment: I added some images to demonstrate what I'm talking about. I don't think I was clear enough

Comment: "When I created it, though, I set it's frame equal to the frame of the second square on the grid." Right, but this raises two questions you are still not answering: (1) _When_ did you set it? Timing is everything. And (2) what is causing the grid to get bigger even though the card is not?

Comment: To answer the first question, I set the frame in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller. That likely won't be where it stays. I just wanted to mess around with it to make sure it was working.

To answer the second, the grid is being resized by auto-layout constraints I added to the view on the storyboard.

Comment: Well, my answer (revised) explains that you're doing it too early. So what you are seeing is exactly what you should expect to see. You're setting the button frame to the nib grid. Then the grid is resized to fit the actual window - but of course the button is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use auto layout to position / size things, so that they will have the same relative arrangement no matter how big the screen is. "Set the frame" is the *opposite* of auto layout. Don't set any frames; use auto layout throughout.

Alternatively you *can* use frames, but then timing becomes crucial. You need to wait until after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because only then does the grid have the size it will actually have when it appears. If you do set a card's frame too early (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`), you will be using the nib grid size, not the runtime grid size.

Comment: The problem stems from me adding the button programmatically, I guess. I have to give it a frame, don't I? Is there a way to give it a frame that doesn't involve giving it static values? And since the grid boxes are auto-resizing because of the autolayout constraints, I just assumed that the frame values would too, which would allow me to just set the frame to whatever the value of the box's frame is on that device.

Comment: "I have to give it a frame, don't I" No, you don't. You have to give it a frame _or constraints_. A frame is static. Constraints are auto layout. They are opposites. You want to use constraints, not a frame.

Comment: So I can add constraints to the card button programmatically? If you couldn't guess from the question, I'm still new to iOS development, so I wasn't aware that this was a thing.

Comment: "So I can add constraints to the card button programmatically" Absolutely. You can and perhaps you should. But if you don't, then yes, the card frame will be static while the grid will change size due to autolayout. What you're seeing is exactly what you should expect to see. Frames are static. Constraints make things dynamic.

Comment: So it appears you are in an auto layout world without having the foggiest notion what auto layout _is_. Maybe it would help you to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the frame instead of it use the `auto layout constraint`.
Create the place card button and `addsubview` it on any Rectangles button/view then add constraints programmatically. Try the [`KVConstraintExtensionsMaster`](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) library.

```
By Using KVConstraintExtensionsMaster library, put the below code from where you want to place new card upon Ractangle Buttons either 

   UIButton *placeCardButton = [UIButton prepareNewViewForAutoLayout];
   [placeCardButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [self.secondRactangleButton prepareViewForAutoLayout];
   // here self.secondRactangleButton is IBOutlet reference.
   [self.secondRactangleButton addSubview:placeCardButton];

   // now adding all required constraints on the button
   [placeCardButton applyConstraintFitToSuperview];

Or Direct Without using library 

    UIButton * placeCardButton = [UIButton new];
    [placeCardButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [placeCardButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.secondRactangleButton addSubview:placeCardButton];

    [self.secondRactangleButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[placeCardButton]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(placeCardButton)]];
    [self.secondRactangleButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[placeCardButton]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(placeCardButton)]];
```